# Azure Functions launched from VS Code gives ssl error

Tags: python, ssl, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I've created an Azure Function - HTTP Trigger in VS Code but I face an error related to SSL.
As a summary, I would like the function to read a csv file from one blob storage container ( works ), and then generate another .txt file and upload it to a different blob storage container ( this part seems to generate the ssl error ).
Can't seem to find the root of the problem, does somebody has an idea on how to approach it?

Python Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import logging
import azure.functions as func
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, generate_container_sas, ContainerSasPermissions, generate_blob_sas, BlobSasPermissions, ContainerClient
from azure.core.exceptions import HttpResponseError, ResourceExistsError
import time
import os
import uuid

# using generate_container_sas
def get_img_url_with_container_sas_token(account_name,container_name,account_key):
    container_sas_token = generate_container_sas(
        account_name=account_name,
        container_name=container_name,
        account_key=account_key,
        permission=ContainerSasPermissions(read=True),
        expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1)
    )
    return container_sas_token

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = "xxxxx"
    key =  "xxxxx"
    raw_container = "raw"
    blob_name = 'employee.csv'

    gen_token = get_img_url_with_container_sas_token(name,raw_container,key)
    INPUTSTORAGEACCOUNTURLSAS = f"https://{name}.blob.core.windows.net/{raw_container}/{blob_name}?{gen_token}"

    #df = pd.read_csv(INPUTSTORAGEACCOUNTURLSAS,delimiter=',')

    connect_str ='xxxxx'
    # Create a file in local data directory to upload and download 
    local_file_name = "quickstart" + str(uuid.uuid4()) + ".txt"
    upload_file_path = "xxxxx" + local_file_name

    # Write text to the file
    file = open(upload_file_path, 'w')
    file.write("Hello, World!")
    file.close()

    container_name = 'proccessed'
   # Create a blob client using the local file name as the name for the blob
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
    blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=local_file_name)

    print("\nUploading to Azure Storage as blob:\n\t" + local_file_name)

    # Upload the created file
    with open(upload_file_path, "rb") as data: 
        #print(data)
        blob_client.upload_blob(data) 

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )
```

Error resulted:

```
Executed 'Functions.ecr_xml_to_dl' (Failed, Id=7190b60c-4f2c-4c14-ad3c-b76735405953, Duration=96214ms)
[2020-12-07T12:27:42.443Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.ecr_xml_to_dl. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
Exception: ServiceRequestError: [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:852)
Stack:   File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.6/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 349, in _handle__invocation_request
    self.__run_sync_func, invocation_id, fi.func, args)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 56, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.6/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 511, in __run_sync_func
    return func(**params)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Work\Coding\Azure_Test_Function\ecr_xml_to_dl\__init__.py", line 58, in main
    blob_client.upload_blob(data)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\azure\core\tracing\decorator.py", line 83, in wrapper_use_tracer
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blob\_blob_client.py", line 539, in upload_blob
    return upload_block_blob(**options)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blob\_upload_helpers.py", line 106, in upload_block_blob
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blob\_generated\operations\_block_blob_operations.py", line 217, in upload
    pipeline_response = self._client._pipeline.run(request, stream=False, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\azure\core\pipeline\_base.py", line 211, in run
    return first_node.send(pipeline_request)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\azure\core\pipeline\_base.py", line 71, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\azure\core\pipeline\_base.py", line 71, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\azure\core\pipeline\_base.py", line 71, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  [Previous line repeated 2 more times]
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\azure\core\pipeline\policies\_redirect.py", line 157, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\azure\core\pipeline\_base.py", line 71, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blob\_shared\policies.py", line 515, in send
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blob\_shared\policies.py", line 489, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\azure\core\pipeline\_base.py", line 71, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\azure\core\pipeline\_base.py", line 71, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\azure\core\pipeline\_base.py", line 71, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  [Previous line repeated 1 more time]
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blob\_shared\policies.py", line 290, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\azure\core\pipeline\_base.py", line 71, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\azure\core\pipeline\_base.py", line 71, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\azure\core\pipeline\_base.py", line 103, in send
    self._sender.send(request.http_request, **request.context.options),
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blob\_shared\base_client.py", line 319, in send
    return self._transport.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\azure\core\pipeline\transport\_requests_basic.py", line 285, in send
    raise error
```

Comment: May I know the error message shows in which line of the code ?

Comment: If the error message doesn't show line number, please add `logging.info("111")`, `logging.info("222")`... between each row to check which line of code trigger the error.

Comment: Hi Shen, I've updated the question with the full error message, thank you!

Comment: Hi, is the `upload_file_path` like `C:\\xxx\\xxx\\filename.txt` ? Or the `upload_file_path` includes `http/https` in it ?

Comment: @HuryShen the upload_file_path is like C:\\xxx\\xxx\\filename.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to some test, it seems your code is no problem, the code work fine in my side.

For the error message you provided, it seems was caused by your internet connect. If your computer uses proxy to connect to internet, it may show similar problem. So please check if your network uses any proxy or if open fiddler in your computer. And please change another computer with public internet to test with same code.

Comment: Hi Hury, you are right, the proxy was the one that caused the problem. I've solved it now, thank you!

Comment: @PyRar Great, could you please mark my answer as "accepted", thanks.