# Visual Studio Code - Local Debugging - SSL - Connection Forcibly Closed By Remote Host

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I've created an Azure function.
Getting the components such as Azure Core Tools has been a battle due to the proxy / firewall policies.
When debugging locally a basic example for instance Azures default HTTP Trigger unaltered the Virtual Environment spins up and the command `func host start` runs.
At this point it finds Python, runs a pip install, then errors out.

It looks like a Proxy issue, but that's been opened up, has anyone had any experience with the below error when locally debugging an Azure Function?

System.Net.Http: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. System.Net.Sockets: Unable to read
data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.. An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')

Edit: After having no hope I had a look in Internet Options and changed to "Use SSL 3.0".
Now the error doesn't come up, instead I get the following;

System.IO.Compression: End of Central Directory record could not be found.
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Hello @Dan, provide us the code you're working! If it the default Azure Function Code, working from our end!

Comment: Thanks, Our IT team have managed to fix this by changing Proxy settings.
It was the default code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Dan for solving the issue,

> Our IT team have managed to fix this by changing Proxy settings.

When using the Company's System/VPN, we may face some issues while accessing the APIs in internet from browser or Code Editors, etc.

As You're using the Azure Functions in VS Code, I found few helpful documents to understand the issues better:

- [Proxy server support on VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/network#_proxy-server-support)
- [VS Code Azure Functions Proxy Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65209248) related [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60189658) & [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azurefunctions/issues/493).
- [How to use azure-functions-core-tools behind corporate proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66419880/how-to-use-azure-functions-core-tools-behind-corporate-proxy)